# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Tk'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pycharm

I started to learn GUI developement using the Tkinter python library but I faced a problem with the PyCharm IDE community edition 4.5.2

My problem is: when I write the code below in the IDLE, it works fine!!!
but when I write it using the the PyCharm IDE, this error message appears:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Tk' 
Please help me, I really need help and thank you a lot

My code:

```
import Tkinter

app = Tkinter.Tk()
app.title("hello world")
app.minsize(300, 300)
helloLabel = Tkinter.Label(app, text="hello GUI")
helloLabel.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Note: I'm using Python 2.7.6, OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Did you name your file `Tkinter.py`?

Comment: yes sir it's Tkinter.py

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you named your file `Tkinter.py`. When you do the import, python sees the file and tries to import it instead of the Tkinter library.

Rename your file, and be sure to remove `Tkinter.pyc` if it exists.